# Why is the accuracy difference so much when I use the image data set and pytorch's own data set directly?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, pytorch, torchvision

For example, for the cifar10 data set, directly using the data set that comes with pytorch, the accuracy rate can reach 96% under the same network structure, but after I converted cifar10 into a picture, I tested it and the accuracy rate was only 92%. why?

This is the previous code：

```
train_dataset = dset.CIFAR10(args.data_path, train=True, transform=train_transform, download=True)
test_dataset = dset.CIFAR10(args.data_path, train=False, transform=test_transform, download=True)
```

This is the modified code：

```
train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='/home/ubuntu/bigdisk/DataSets/cifar10/static/orig/train/',
                                         transform=train_transform
                                         )
test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='/home/ubuntu/bigdisk/DataSets/cifar10/static/orig/test/',
                                        transform=test_transform
                                        )
```

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True,
                                               num_workers=args.prefetch, pin_memory=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=args.test_bs, shuffle=False,
                                              num_workers=args.prefetch, pin_memory=True)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. From where do you get your data? Here is where PyTorch's data coming from: 

`base_folder = 'cifar-10-batches-py'
 url = "https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz"
 filename = "cifar-10-python.tar.gz"`

Comment: My data is to convert CIFAR-10 python version into img

Answer (score 2):

If the downloaded dataset, hyperparameters(such as batch size or learning rate), dataset transformation, etc were equal, I think it is because the randomness.

Your dataloader shuffles the dataset randomly. The shuffled dataset will always be different every time you shuffle it, which might have led to the accuracy difference.

Also, the model will be initialized with different values each time. (Unless you have used some initialization method that always initializes the model with the same values.)

You could check https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
As shown in the code above, I just modified the path to load the data set from ~/DATASETS/cifar.python to root='/home/ubuntu/bigdisk/DataSets/cifar10/static/orig/train/, Others such as train_transform have not changed. Only the path has changed. Using cifar.python, it can reach more than 96% each time, while using the img path converted by cifar.python, the accuracy rate is only 92% each time.

Comment: this is the img :
![](https://ypyssl.machunjie.com/machunjie/20200812143211.png)

Comment: @Arvin So you are saying two datasets are identical. As I said in the answer, it is likely because of the randomness. Please check the link and retrain on two datasets with reproducibility options on and compare the results.